# Issue with case null in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Id 
FROM dbo.OWL_AddlDataFields 
WHERE CustomerId = @BaseCustomerId 
  AND AddlDataFieldCategoryId = @AddlDataFieldCategoryId 
  AND AddlDataFieldGroupId = CASE 
                                WHEN @AddlDataFieldGroupId =  0 THEN  NULL 
                                ELSE  @AddlDataFieldGroupId 
                             END  
  AND Name = @DataFieldName
```

The above query does not returns any result. I think above query has issue with the 'AddlDataFieldCategoryId =' and the null from the case.  Can anybody correct the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your `CASE` expression is that you are comparing a column to a predicate which might be `NULL` using the equals operator.  This won't behave as expected, because `NULL` comparisons should use `IS NULL` instead of equals.  One possible workaround would be to coalesce `AddlDataFieldGroupId` to a numeric value.  Then, we can be certain that the `CASE` expression would only be comparing one number to another.

```
WHERE ... AND
COALESCE(AddlDataFieldGroupId, 0) = CASE WHEN 
                    @AddlDataFieldGroupId =  0
                                         THEN 0 ELSE  @AddlDataFieldGroupId END
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `AddlDataFieldGroupId` cannot be zero, then you don't need the `CASE` at all. This will do the job:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM dbo.OWL_AddlDataFields 
WHERE CustomerId = @BaseCustomerId 
AND AddlDataFieldCategoryId = @AddlDataFieldCategoryId 
AND AddlDataFieldGroupId = @AddlDataFieldGroupId
AND Name = @DataFieldName
```

If `AddlDataFieldGroupId` can be zero, but cannot be negative, you can do this:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM dbo.OWL_AddlDataFields 
WHERE CustomerId = @BaseCustomerId 
AND AddlDataFieldCategoryId = @AddlDataFieldCategoryId 
AND AddlDataFieldGroupId = CASE WHEN 
@AddlDataFieldGroupId =  0 THEN -1 ELSE @AddlDataFieldGroupId END  
AND Name = @DataFieldName
```

Alternatively, this will work regardless of what `AddlDataFieldGroupId` can be:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM dbo.OWL_AddlDataFields 
WHERE CustomerId = @BaseCustomerId 
AND AddlDataFieldCategoryId = @AddlDataFieldCategoryId 
AND AddlDataFieldGroupId = CASE WHEN 
@AddlDataFieldGroupId =  0 THEN AddlDataFieldGroupId - 1 ELSE @AddlDataFieldGroupId END  
AND Name = @DataFieldName
```

Note: all these solutions assume that `AddlDataFieldGroupId` cannot be `NULL`.